# Do I have to free dynamically allocated memory if I use all of it?

Tags: c

If I dynamically allocate memory of a specific size and I use all of the size I allocated do I still have to free the pointer I used to allocate said memory?
To be more specific, I want to allocate memory for a string only after I input the string. Meaning I don't know the size I need to allocate until after I input it.
And if I allocate exactly as much as I need and use all of it do I still have to free it after I'm done with it?

EDIT:
For those wondering, here's the function I'm writing:

```
student* Create_Class(int size)
{
    struct stud *Arr;
    int i, j, k;
    char YourName[51];
    int length;
    Arr = (struct stud*)malloc(size * sizeof(struct stud));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf(" %s", YourName);
        length = strlen(YourName);
        (Arr + i)->name = (char*)malloc(length * sizeof(char));
        for (k = 0; k < length; k++)
            (Arr + i)->name[k] = YourName[k];
        (Arr + i)->name[k] = '\0';
        printf("Enter your marks: ");
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            scanf("%d", &(Arr + i)->marks[j]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        Avg_Mark(Arr + i);
    return Arr;
}
```

Obviously I can't free the pointer at the end of the function so I have to free it in the main function but when I do so it simply crashes.
I need to free all of the memory I allocate for each name field, then for the actual array but it crashes for some reason.

Comment: you can use `realloc` with a smaller size than the start. Of course you have to free any memory you're allocating, used or not!

Comment: Do you have a problem with using to much memory, or is the question hypothetical?

Comment: The project requires that I scan a name no longer than 50 characters, then use strlen to identify its length then allocate memory the size of the length using the name field as the pointer.

Comment: in the main function you have to make sure that the pointer is freed `before` the Arr struct is freed and only if it is no longer needed. Otherwise it could cause the crash.

Comment: I advice you to post a new (don't edit this one) question where you ask about why your program crashes, since this looks like [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/374458). Be sure to include a [mcve] in your question, with emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: (Arr + i)->name = (char*)malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char)); 
As long as you want to use this structure array in your application, its memory should remain allocated. 
After you are done with it you have to release the Name field first and then release the structure's memory itself.

Comment: Yes I tried but it crashes when I try to release the name pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You need to free no matter what.

You are basically renting a chunk of memory from the operating system (exactly what happens is platform dependent) when you call `malloc`. What you are doing when you call `free` is that you promise to not use the memory chunk again, so the operating system can use it for other purposes. The OS does not know if you have used everything or not, and it does not care.

> I want to allocate memory for a string only after I input the string.

If you want to adjust that size of memory after allocation, then use `realloc`. However, it is not a good use for your particular scenario. When you call `malloc` you may get a larger chunk than you asked for. This has some benefits. If you choose to `realloc` to get a larger memory chunk, your data does not need to be moved and the reallocation will go faster. When you call `malloc` you get (if success) a pointer to a memory chunk that is *at least* the size you asked for. It may be bigger or the same size. Remember though that this also applies for `realloc`. You can ask the operating system to decrease the chunk of memory that is allocated, but you have no guarantee that this will actually happen.

Important: Remember that even though `malloc` and `realloc` may return a pointer to a bigger memory chunk than you asked for, you should NEVER use more than you asked for. Doing so will cause undefined behavior.

But I would say that this sounds a lot like unnecessary microoptimization.

Comment: I wouldn't say "from the operating system" but "from the heap". The heap may get it from the OS (the [virtual] memory manager), but it is released upon program termination anyway.

Comment: Neither would I say "When you call malloc you may get a larger chunk than you asked for. [....]" and this is simply not true. The heap may have memory beyond the chunk given to you available, but it doesn't have to and writing there will cause undefined behavior. So you simply don't know that, don't get it and may _never_ use or assume that.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie -- heaps are implementation details, not C language details. The allocation may or may not be released upon program termination, again depending on the OS.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I fixed a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Freeing memory is not like returning what you have not used. It is more like giving back what you have borrowed (without interest of course!!).

Since you know what the `size` of the `stud` array is going to be when you call `Create_Class`, when you return from it, you can iterate through the `stud` elements in the `Arr` and free the memory allocated to each of the names.
Finally, you can free the whole `Arr`.

Freeing is usually done in the reverse order of allocation. What's allocated first is freed last and what is allocated last is freed first.